# .NET Core + Nginx losing HTTP Header

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core

I'm sending HTTP GET Request to my API with custom Header

```
var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("__Test", data);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Everything works fine on localhost, but when I deploy API on server which is using Nginx then this header is "lost"

That's my nginx config

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

This works fine on localhost, but not on server:

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("__Test", out var data)
```

Anybody has an idea what can go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Problem occured because I used `__` in header's name

Solution:

Use

`underscores_in_headers on;`

in

`nginx.conf`